# (Direct) Desktop app to Android app communication via GCM / FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently evaluating my possibilities for a possible future project and thus I want to clarify if I have any misunderstandings.

So if I understood it correctly, Firebase Cloud Messaging is usually intended to allow communication between one authority (for example the developer of the app) and many app installations, for example in order to send notifications/news to the app users, right?

I am planning on developing a tool, where users can set up an Android app and a Desktop app (for example maybe a Browser add-on), and those two pieces of software should be able to communicate with each other. Now traditionally, what you would need is an intermediary server backend (since end-to-end connection would require that both softwares know the ip address of each other, and additionally that the network ports are open), right?

I am now wondering if you could transcendent that problem by using Firebase Cloud Messaging, particularly by showing the [registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#access_the_registration_token) to the user in the Android app screen, which he can then paste to the Desktop app? I am just seeking some confirmation (or refutation) here.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is designed facilitate a push notification. It is based off of GCM core architecture. Essentially you register your device with FCM and you send your Token to your server. When your server wants to send a Push notification it uses the Token to send it to your specific device or a group of devices.

FCM alone is probably not what you are looking for. FCM is generally for communication from server to device. It does not facilitate communication the other way. The best solution here would be just setting up a server that is an intermediary between the two.

Or

You can use firebase other tools in addition to FCM. Communication between Desktop App and Device is established with FCM. You can send notifications all day TO the app on device. Firebase also has a database which means you can push data to firebase from the app using firebase sdk. There is your communication from android app to desktop app. You desktop app would just need to subscribe to changes in your firebase database. You can even use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to trigger your events based on your data in the firebase database.

OR

If you were only concerned about local you could set up a local node server and some socket connections or api endpoints. You would need to have the ports open on the computer in question as well as those same ports set up to forward to that computer on your router. Then the device would need to use that computers ip address and port number to proxy it connection.